# Pokemon Go issue with pokestops and gyms

Tags: pokemon-go

I have been playing Pokemon Go for about 2 weeks. I'm level 16. I jailbroke my phone one day. Everything worked fine. Then my jailbreak broke. Now my Pokemon go won't show and gyms pokestops or nearby Pokemon.  Help?

Comment: @Frank Do we support jailbreaking?

Answer (score 2):

The game is known to have detection for jailbreaks.

It is very possible that you've been shadowbanned for having a jailbroken phone (and maybe cheating?).

Additionally, if you're on iOS 9.2.X or higher, you need to re-apply the Pangu jailbreak after a reboot, and install a mod like Masterball to defeat jailbreak detection. Note that this mod does *not* disable cheat detection, as it's serverside.